# Find a line that passes through a point and cuts two lines

Tags: geometry, vectors

I know there are similar questions here but I can't understand them. This one, for example
[Find the line that intersects two other lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788916/find-the-line-that-intersects-two-other-lines)

So, in my problem I have to find the line named $T$ that passes through the point $(1,1,0)$ and cuts line $$r: \left\{ \begin{array}{l} x+z=0  \\y=-2 \end{array} \right. 
\qquad \qquad 
s: \left\{ \begin{array}{l} x=1  \\y-z+3=0 \end{array}
\right.$$. \
The thing is that I don't really understand what to do. I mean, the why of doing something.

Comment: If a line cuts two other lines, then it passes through their intersection. Thus all you have to do is to determine (if there exists) the intersection between $r$ and $s$.

Comment: That makes sense but then what should I do with the given point? Should I replace it by x y z and see if it is okay or do anythin different/else?

Comment: @user1337: The question does not specifier whether line $T$ meets lines $r$ and $s$ at the smae point. Are these to lines coplanar?

Comment: The exercise only says that $T$ cuts them.

Comment: @user1337 This is not at all the same thing as the three lines being coincident. A single line can cut a pair of parallel lines, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Denote $A$ the point with coordinates $(1,1,0)$. This point, together with $r$ determines a plane $\Pi$  belonging to the pencil of planes with basis the planes $x+z=0$, $y+2=0$, i.e. its equation is
$$\lambda(x+z)+\mu(y+2)=0,\quad \lambda,\mu\in\mathbf R.$$
Note that these coefficients are defined up to a nonzero factor.

Determine the coefficients $\lambda,\mu$. If $B$ is the intersection of line $s$ with $\Pi$, the sought line is  $(AB)$.

*Variant*: Determine in the same way the equation of the plane $\Pi'$ defined by $A$ and the line $s$. The sought line in the intersection of $\Pi$ and $\Pi'$.

Comment: Moreover, one can use Plücker’s mu to write down equations for these two planes directly. For instance, an equation for $\Pi$ Is $(1\cdot1+1\cdot0)(y+2)-(1\cdot1+2)(x+z)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The line to be found must be coplanar to the straights r and s and passing through $T(1,1,0)$.
The equation of such a line, written in parametric form is as follows:

$\frac{x-1}{l}=\frac{y-1}{m}=\frac{z}{n}$.

For two straights to be coplanar, the determinant

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_{2}-x_{1}& y_{2}-y_{1}& z_{2}-z_{1}\\
l&m&m\\
l_{0}&m_{0}&n_{0}\end{pmatrix}$$,

must be null.

Substituting to $ l_{0},m_{0},n_{0}$,once the parameters of the line r, another time those of the line s,we obtain two equations in $l,m,n$, which solved as a function of $n$, give as a solution:

$l=0,m=3,n=1$.

The equation of our goal becomes:

$x=1, y=3z+1$.